React Query useMutation is getting called so many times
I have a react component that has an useEffect like this:
  // MQTT client
  const client = mqtt.connect(brokerUrl, {
    clientId,
    clean: true,
    username: import.meta.env.VITE_MQTT_BROKER_USERNAME,
    password: import.meta.env.VITE_MQTT_BROKER_PASSWORD,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set up event handlers
    if (client) {
      client.on("connect", () => {
        client.subscribe("rfid", () => {});
      });

      client.on("message", (topic, message) => {
        if (topic === "rfid") {
          handleRfidCard(message.toString());
          // console.log({ message });
        }
      });
    }
  }, [client, handleRfidCard]);

Inside the handleRFID, I call 2 apis using useMutation:
  const rfidCard = useGetRfidCardByPhysicalCard();
  const handleRfidCard = (rfidID: string) => {
    if (rfidID) {
      rfidCard.mutate(rfidID, {
        onSuccess: (data) => {
          capture(data.id, data.type);
        },
      });
      rfidHistory.mutate(rfidID);
    }
  };

Here's an example of my mutation hook:
import { instanceCoreApi } from "@/provider/setupAxios";
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { RFIDCard_API } from "../apis";

export const useGetRfidCardByPhysicalCard = () => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (cardID: string) => {
      const res = await instanceCoreApi.get(RFIDCard_API.GET_BY_CARD_ID, {
        params: {
          cardID,
        },
      });
      return res.data;
    },
  });
};

I expect that each time receive the message from MQTT broker, the 2 apis will be called. Currently, they're being called incrementally, which mean:
#1 message: 2 calls
#2 message: 4 calls
#3 message: 6 calls

This is really confusing as it slows down the web as it gets more messages. Can anyone help me?

Disconnect from the broker server with a cleanup function

It seems like your useEffect runs again after a render because one of its dependencies changed, and you're not cleaning up the old subscription, so new subscriptions are added and with every new message, multiple event handlers are processed.
